# How do you output Json object into a notepad

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, jsonp

I have api's that run and fetch the data as JSON objects.How do I store these objects directly into a database?The database we are using now is SQL Server 2008?Can I store theis data directly into the database.

Next question is ...I'm using Python.How do you export the output(JSON Objects)into a notepad?

Thank You

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! I don't think your question can be completely answered in its current form. First, it's actually two questions (which you should ask separately); second, you'd need to tell us more about what you're expecting to do with the data once they are in the database.

Answer (score 1):

To write a JSON object to a file:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as output:
    json.dump(myJSONobject, output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate more about storing in the database.

By notepad I am assuming you mean to get the data into text file.

```
my_string_to_write = json.dumps(your_raw_json_here)
```

will give you a string that you can write directly to a file.

Comment: Why the detour? Why not dump to a file directly?